# A little help w/ Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am having a little trouble with API arrays. Basically I want to only display the first object of information from the API array. I have been playing around with Slice() and substr() functions and haven't managed to get it to work. I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkg6E/14/) to show you want I mean.

**HTML:**

```
<h3>Wind Speed:</h3><div class='speed'></div> <br>
<h3>Wind Direction:</h3><div class='thug'></div><br>
<h3>Wave Height:</h3><div class='test'></div><br>
<h3>Ignore:</h3><div class='wave'></div><br>
```

**JS:**

```
var url = 'http://magicseaweed.com/api/CP86f5quQqmB1fpW2S3bZVUCS8j1WpUF/forecast/?spot_id=1323'

$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: url
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    sum = 0;

   //---Wind Speed---------------------------------- 
     $.each(data, function(){
        sum += this.wind.speed;
    });
    $('.speed').html(sum / data.length + data[0].wind.unit);



     //---Ignore---------------------------------- 
     $.each(data, function(){
        sum += this.swell.maxBreakingHeight;
    });
    $('.wave').html(sum);


     //---Wave Height---------------------------------- 

    $.each(data, function(){
        $('.test').append('<p>' + this.swell.maxBreakingHeight + '</p>'); 
    });


     //---Wind Direction---------------------------------- 

    $.each(data, function(){
        sum += this.wind.compassDirection ;
    });

    var numbers = sum;
     $('.thug').append('<p>' + numbers.slice( 3,4) + '</p>');
});
```

In this example, I only want it to display the first number which in this case is '4'. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me, Im fairly new to Javascript and I have been scratching my head for ages!

Thanks

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question. Do not only provide a link

Comment: if fiddle is there provide the link...

Comment: There's not even a link.

Comment: @rene: Please fix your edit, you have removed the link!

Comment: @musefan yeah I was trying to fix that but you guys beat me to it.

Comment: @Chandan remember that a jsfiddle link only is not enough. You need to include the code in the question as well.

Comment: @user2379090, What exactly do you need. Whats your expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to get average values for all the timestamps?

Comment: Im trying to get the wave height function to only output one number, rather than an entire list of numbers.

Comment: Is it going to be the average?

Answer (score 1):

To get the average of your values you could do,

```
//---Wave Height---------------------------------- 
    var averageMaxBreakingHeight=0;
    var numberOfValues=0;
    $.each(data, function(){
        averageMaxBreakingHeight+=parseFloat(this.swell.maxBreakingHeight);
            numberOfValues++;
        /*$('.test').append('<p>' + this.swell.maxBreakingHeight + '</p>'); */
    });
    averageMaxBreakingHeight=averageMaxBreakingHeight/numberOfValues;
    $('.test').append('<p>'+averageMaxBreakingHeight+'</p>');


     //---Wind Direction----------------------------------
```

*//below numbers variable can be any variable you need it to be i.e. averageMaxBreakingHeight*

If you just need the units of the decimal number then you can do,

```
numbers.substr(0,numbers.indexOf('.'))
```

To round up,

```
Math.round(parseFloat(numbers));
```

To round your number up to two decimal places do,

```
Math.round(parseFloat(numbers) * 100) / 100;
```